# Pass dynamic parameters into a Table Valued Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions

How do I correctly pass parameters into or JOIN on a Table Valued Function?  The IDs I want to pass into my TVF exist in a table.  I made an attempt to JOIN back to my fakePerson Table and pass those IDs into my TVF however I keep getting the error:

> The multi-part identifier "p.PersonID" could not be bound.

Below is what I have tried:

```
WITH fakePerson AS
(
    SELECT 22804 AS PersonID, 'Daniel Jackson' AS FullName UNION ALL
    SELECT 38415 AS PersonID, 'Jack O''Niel' AS FullName
)
SELECT *
FROM fakePerson p
    /* Of course passing the ID which can change per person record works but I am not able to pass a static personID as I need the ID of the record in question. */
    JOIN dbo.c_RetentionStatsPerEnrollment(p.PersonID) rs ON rs.ClientID = p.PersonID
    --JOIN dbo.c_RetentionStatsPerEnrollment(22804) rs ON rs.ClientID = p.PersonID
WHERE p.PersonID = 22804
;
```

**The correct answer to this question is below after reading comments to this question.  CROSS APPLY.**

```
WITH fakePerson AS
(
    SELECT 22804 AS PersonID, 'Daniel Jackson' AS FullName UNION ALL
    SELECT 38415 AS PersonID, 'Jack O''Niel' AS FullName
)
SELECT *
FROM fakePerson p
    CROSS APPLY dbo.c_RetentionStatsPerEnrollment(p.PersonID)
;
```

Now I can turn the above into a View so I can use the statistics I coded into the Table Valued Function.  I originally planned on using a VIEW to obtain the totals I needed however the SQL became too complex as there were plenty of Aggregate and Window functions being used to filter in/out date records per the enrollments associated with the person.

Comment: You need `CROSS APPLY`

Comment: CROSS APPLY and that link to the MSSQL SO Post was it.  That was what I was missing.

Comment: Please don't add the answer to the question. Add it as an answer if its helpful - which given there is a duplicate its unlikely to be.